# How to catch NULL values in payload using MEL

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How can i catch null values in payload using `MEL`, i am using mule 3.4, most of my payload is in `JSON` and sometimes `XML`.

```
{
   "username": "DEADPOOL",
   "text": "chimichanga",
   "val":null
}
```

Comment: Hi in this case payload is not null but is a json, what you want to do exectly ? Check if the field val is null ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use choice component. 
And try this flow :

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
   <when expression="#[payload.'username' == null]">
              {your code}
   </when>
   <otherwise>
   </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can reference the part of the payload with `payload['username']` which would equal `DEADPOOL`

So you could do something like this

```
if(payload['username'] == null) {
    //do something if it's null
}
else {
    //it's not null
}
```